# how to remove a list iwoth one value nside nested list in python?

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a list as

```
s=[[a,1,2,3],[2],[e,4],[r]]
```

How do I remove the list with only one value inside s?
Please help
Thank you in advance

Comment: please add your expected result.

Comment: I downvoted this. Normally I do not downvote but this one quite clearly could've been answered with a python tutorial available anywhere online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```py
a = e = r = 0
s = [[a, 1, 2, 3], [2], [e, 4], [r]]

results = [sub_list for sub_list in s if len(sub_list) > 1]
print(results)
```

output:

```py
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[l for l in s if len(l) > 1]
```

Is one solution. This will remove all sublists of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

With simple list comprehension:

```
>>> s=[['a',1,2,3],[2],['e',4],['r']]
>>> print([i for i in s if len(i) > 1])
>>> [['a', 1, 2, 3], ['e', 4]]
```